# Easy way to run a function multiple times in parrallel in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to run a function multiple times in parrallel. I've tried multithreading but either there is something I don't understand or it doesn't actually speed up the calculations (actually quite the opposite). I have here the function that I want to run in parrallel:

```
void heun_update_pos(vector<planet>& planets, vector<double> x_i, vector<double> y_i, vector<double> mass, size_t n_planets, double h, int i)
    
    {
    
        if (planets[i].mass != 0) {
            double sum_gravity_x = 0;
            double sum_gravity_y = 0;
    
            //loop for collision check and gravitational contribution
            for (int j = 0; j < n_planets; j++) {
    
                if (planets[j].mass != 0) {
    
                    double delta_x = planets[i].x_position - x_i[j];
                    double delta_y = planets[i].y_position - y_i[j];
    
                    //computing the distances between two planets in x and y
                    if (delta_x != 0 && delta_y != 0) {
                        //collision test
                        if (collision_test(planets[i], planets[j], delta_x, delta_y) == true) {
                            planets[i].mass += planets[j].mass;
                            planets[j].mass = 0;
                        }
    
                        //sum of the gravity contributions from other planets
                        sum_gravity_x += gravity_x(delta_x, delta_y, mass[j]);
                        sum_gravity_y += gravity_y(delta_x, delta_y, mass[j]);
    
                    }
                }
            };
            double sx_ip1 = planets[i].x_speed + (h / 2) * sum_gravity_x;
            double sy_ip1 = planets[i].y_speed + (h / 2) * sum_gravity_y;
            double x_ip1 = planets[i].x_position + (h / 2) * (planets[i].x_speed + sx_ip1);
            double y_ip1 = planets[i].y_position + (h / 2) * (planets[i].y_speed + sy_ip1);
            planets[i].update_position(x_ip1, y_ip1, sx_ip1, sy_ip1);
        };
    
    }
```

An here is my how I tried to use multithreading with it:

```
    const int cores = 6;
    vector<thread> threads(cores);
    int active_threads = 0;
    int closing_threads = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < n_planets; i++) {

        threads[active_threads] = thread(&Heun_update_pos, ref(planets), x_i, y_i, mass, n_planets, h, i);

        if (i > cores - 2) threads[closing_threads].join();

        //There should only be as many threads as there are cores
        closing_threads++;
        if (closing_threads > cores - 1) closing_threads = 0;

        active_threads++; // counting the number of active threads
        if (active_threads >= cores) active_threads = 0;

    };

    //CLOSING REMAINING THREADS
    for (int k = 0; k < cores; k++) {
        if (threads[k].joinable()) threads[k].join();
    };
```

I just started learning C++ today (used Python before), this is my first code, so I am not very familiar with all the C++ functionalities.

Comment: How long your serial version takes?

Comment: Use parallel standard algorithms, e.g. `std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, ...)`.

Comment: Something feels off about the approach used to limit/join active threads.

Comment: As a test function, I'd suggest `sleep()`, not anything complicated. Then, throw some output on the console whenever you start or join a thread. I guess that will tell you what's happening.

Comment: Maybe you could start with `std::async`. That has a lower overhead . . .

Comment: I read about for_each but I'm not sure I understand how it works. The serial version runs fine, I'm just trying to get the benefits of c++. I'm running a simulation of a group of planets interacting with each other. For now I can put about 500 of them at a time (without implementing any fancy algorithms) with the animation staying at 60 fps, anything more affects the performance.

Answer (score 1):

Creating new threads take a lot of time, typically 50-100 microseconds. Depending on how long your serial version takes, it would really not be very helpful. If you run this code several times, it would be worth trying to use a thread pool since waking up a thread takes max 5 microseconds.

Check out a similar answer here:

[Is there a performance benefit in using a pool of threads over simply creating threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70465478/is-there-a-performance-benefit-in-using-a-pool-of-threads-over-simply-creating-t/70466270#70466270)

There is a framework for multithreading calculation in C++ called OpenMP. You might think about using it.

https://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/